# Searching for and deleting orphaned items in a mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have several records that have no value for there name because the parent record has been deleted.

```
select * from `aow_processed` where `aow_workflow_id` like ""
```

returns all these records. I'm not sure of the next command to in turn delete the found records.

```
select * from `aow_processed` where `aow_workflow_id` like ""
```

Comment: Read more about the [delete command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe missing something but have you tried this?

```
delete from aow_processed where aow_workflow_id like ""
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, thank you! I was over thinking it and thought I had to select records beforehand.